# Move Calendar event to Reminders?

Tags: macos, calendar, reminders

I have some events on my Calendar that I would prefer to have listed in Reminders.  (They were added to the Calendar by TurboTax.)  Is there a simple way to move them from one app to another?  (I'm using Mac OS 10.11.6.)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

1. Open your calendar.
2. Click on the event you want to move to Reminders.
3. Copy the event (<kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
4. In the Reminders app, click in a new event line.
5. Paste the event (<kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

There are a couple things I noticed when testing this (on Mac OS Sierra, 10.12.6):

- The title of the reminder matches the name of the calendar event, but it's followed by "Scheduled:".
- If the calendar event contains any alerts prior to the time of the event, these alerts are not added to the reminder.  The reminder is only for the actual time of the event.

Comment: This is not creating a reminder out of events, but a description on how to copy your own data from the event, isn't it? That doesn't make this a proper answer. At best, it's a workaround, which is very welcome in these circumstances (no apparent solution), but an answer to the question it isn't.

Comment: Calendar items and reminders aren't the same thing, so there really isn't a way for a calendar item to appear in Reminders without creating a new document.  Also, the OP asked how to move an item from a calendar to Reminders, so this answer seems legitimate to me.

Comment: You're *not* moving or connecting the item from calendar to reminders, so why pretend that's what you're doing?

Comment: It sounds like we’re getting hung up on differences in semantics. Perhaps this solution works for the OP. Perhaps it doesn’t. Regardless, it’s one of multiple workarounds, and the answer you posted also seems like a good one.

Comment: This is about methodology, effort and actual results. CopyPasting is both trivial as well as obvious and also is known by almost every computer user. Maybe you have never experienced apps that connect info to each other, that would for example a) display the connected item in both apps and b) take you to this connected item in other app with a click. I have. That Apple won't offer something as useful as that is of course on them.  In the light of that idea my suggestion isn't improving much, even if you can click on the url in the reminder to get to the calendar event.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to work around this limitation of OS X / macOS is by drag and drop.

1. Open Calendar and Reminders.
2. Display the Reminders list to where you want to create the item.
3. Select the event in Calendar and drag it into the list itself.

The only upside with this method would appear to be that you create a link from the reminder to the event in your Calendar schema and date and time at the point creation is visible in Reminder. However, this is probably of limited use as if you reschedule the event this info text is not updated and the link doesn't seem to update either if you change the date. So I'd view this more of saving the user a few key presses at best — sometimes with a lot of info that really helps — and maybe getting some logging info on the original scheduled date. Seemingly there is **not** more info than the copy paste method as suggested by @**Alan Kinnaman**.

It would be much nicer if you could drag and drop also a Reminder to the Calendar, but this doesn't seem to be possible.

Likely the best way to connect Reminders and Calendar is to use an app that is backed by their stores and do link these in its own way. If such apps exist. There are at least apps that integrate calendar and tasks, but if these are backed by the Calendar and Reminder app stores needs to be investigated.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes looking for a way for the System to accomplish small things -  especially now with High Sierra having been trimmed of so many useful “small things” - it makes more sense to copy and paste your Calendar event title to a new Reminder, and fill in the details yourself.

Or search the web.

I find Apple Support very low on advice, mostly a repeat of uninformative Support pages. There are great utilities like Onyx and Cocktail which help with sensible system tweaks.